# How is it possible to use dual core in opengl game loop?

Tags: android, opengl-es, core-graphics, game-loop

My question is about game loop design in opengl.

I believe that game loop can be spited in 3 main steps

1. accept input - it may come from users click on the screen or system alert, or anything else.
2. do logic
3. update view

To make it simple let's just focus on step 2 and 3.

I think that it will be wrong to run them in parallel order or to mix them in to one step.
I give you an example.

Lats say you are creating a war game, and you need to draw 100 soldiers fighting on the screen, the logic will be to update their position, to update the background area, and then you need to draw the result. You can't start drawing one soldier before updated the position of another soldier.

So according this simple steps, it is clear that step 2 and 3 need to be synchronized some how, and step 2 must be done before step 3.

Now tell me how it is possible to run game loop on more then one thread, and more then one process? Does opnegl use multiCore? How?

**Edit:** one way to use multithreading is to precalculate the game logic, or in another words using Vectors. But there are two big disadvantages in vectors that make them almost unrecommend to use.

1. Some times you wan't to change your vector, so there were lots of calculation that you did and you are not going to use them
2. in most of the cases you are trying to reach 60+ FPS witch mean 16 milliseconds for game-loop, switching threads requires some kind of synchronization, any synchronization is bad for performance, from what I saw, even a simple Handler.post() in android(just adding task to queue to run it on other thread) may take up to 3 milliseconds(18% from your frame rate time), so unless your calculation take longer then that, don't do it! For now I did not found anything taking so much time.

Comment: This question is probably best answered on [gamedev.se](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now tell me how it is possible to run game loop on more then one thread

The idea of multicore computing is parallelization, i.e. splitting up computational intensive tasks into independent working sets that can be processed in parallel. Games have surprisingly little space for parallelization, as you found out yourself.

The usual way to use multiple cores in games is to parallelize I/O with logic operations. I.e. doing all the networking and user interaction in one thread, AI and scene management in another. Sound is usually parallelized away, too.

> Does OpenGL use multiCore? How?

The OpenGL specification doesn't specify this. But some implementations may choose to utilize multiple cores. though it's quite unlikely. Why? Because it creates unneccessary cache management overhead.

Comment: Nice saying, but you only say what was the obvious, today most of the computers and even phones come with more then just one core(you can find even 12 cores in apples PC today), computer engineers working to provide us more cores. We, developers, and the most requested those days, game developers, not always can use it. I want  to open people mind for that, for what is really performance about, and can it be possible that so many engineers are workings on cores for nothing... P.S SP3 got 7 cores and it's a game console.

Comment: @Baibu: Well, the Cell SPUs can be utilized for things like AI parallelization or sound effects. Also physics simulation can be parallelized very well.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to explain graphically, why 2 threads, one for rendering and one for logic are much better and doesn't result in inconsistencies:

The single threaded design you proposed would run as follows:

```
logic    |-----|     |-----|
graphics       |-----|     |-----| and so forth.
```

but as you have multiple cpus, you should utilize them. That means, after the first time the logic has finished, the graphics can render that game state. meanwhile, the next logic step can be calculated:

```
logic    |-----||-----||-----|
graphics       |-----||-----|    and so forth.
```

As you see, you can almost double your performance in this way: of course there is some overhead, but it will be faster than the single threaded version anyway.

Also, you can assume, that the game logic will take less time calculating then the render thread: This makes the threading quite easy, because you can wait in the logic thread for a call back from the renderthread to give the render thread new instructions and then calculating the next logic step.